# print all the languages in a single pdf using itext

Tags: itext, xmlworker

Hi I want to print all the languages in a single pdf. My code would be as below .I am not able to see any of characters other than english in my pdf.Please check the attachment for generated pdf.

I can not understand where the real problem exists

```
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;

import com.itextpdf.text.Document;
import com.itextpdf.text.DocumentException;
import com.itextpdf.text.Element;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPCell;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPTable;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter;
import com.itextpdf.tool.xml.ElementList;
import com.itextpdf.tool.xml.XMLWorker;
import com.itextpdf.tool.xml.XMLWorkerFontProvider;
import com.itextpdf.tool.xml.css.StyleAttrCSSResolver;
import com.itextpdf.tool.xml.html.CssAppliers;
import com.itextpdf.tool.xml.html.CssAppliersImpl;
import com.itextpdf.tool.xml.html.Tags;
import com.itextpdf.tool.xml.parser.XMLParser;
import com.itextpdf.tool.xml.pipeline.css.CSSResolver;
import com.itextpdf.tool.xml.pipeline.css.CssResolverPipeline;
import com.itextpdf.tool.xml.pipeline.end.ElementHandlerPipeline;
import com.itextpdf.tool.xml.pipeline.html.HtmlPipeline;
import com.itextpdf.tool.xml.pipeline.html.HtmlPipelineContext;

public class ParseHtml7 {
    public static final String DEST = "arabic.pdf";
    public static final String HTML =  "<html><head></head><body style=\"font-size:12.0pt; font-family:Times New Roman\">"+ "<p>This is hindi language testपरीक्षण </p> "
            +"<p>This is tamil language test சோதனை </p>"
            +"<p>   This is maly language test ujian </p>"
            +"<p>   This is thai language test ทดสอบ</p>"
            +"<p>   This is viyatamese language test thử nghiệm</p>"
            +"<p>   This is khmer language test ការធ្វើតេស្ត</p>"
            +"<p>   This is arabic language test اختبار</p>"
            +"<p>   This is french language test tester</p>"
            +"<p>   This is russian language test контрольная работа</p>"
            +"<p>   This is korean language test 테스트</p>"
            +"<p>   This is japanese language test テスト</p>"
            +"  <p>This is chinese language test 测试</p>"
            +"</body></html>";

    public static void main(String\[\] args) throws IOException, DocumentException {
        File file = new File(DEST);
        //file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
        new ParseHtml7().createPdf(DEST);
    }

    /**
     * Creates a PDF with the words "Hello World"
     * @param file
     * @throws IOException
     * @throws DocumentException
     */
    public void createPdf(String file) throws IOException, DocumentException {
        // step 1
        Document document = new Document();
        // step 2
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(file));
        // step 3
        document.open();
        // step 4
        // Styles
        CSSResolver cssResolver = new StyleAttrCSSResolver();
        XMLWorkerFontProvider fontProvider = new XMLWorkerFontProvider(XMLWorkerFontProvider.DONTLOOKFORFONTS);
        //fontProvider.register("resources/fonts/NotoNaskhArabic-Regular.ttf");
        fontProvider.register("/Users/user/Downloads/MyFonts/FreeSans.ttf");
        fontProvider.register("/Users/user/Downloads/MyFonts/THSarabunNew.ttf");
        fontProvider.register("/Users/user/Downloads/MyFonts/Kh-Content.ttf");
        fontProvider.register("/Users/user/Downloads/MyFonts/THSarabunNew Italic.ttf");
        fontProvider.register("/Users/user/Downloads/MyFonts/THSarabunNew BoldItalic.ttf");
        fontProvider.register("/Users/user/Downloads/MyFonts/THSarabunNew Bold.ttf");
        fontProvider.register("/Users/user/Downloads/MyFonts/arial.ttf");
        fontProvider.register("/Users/user/Downloads/MyFonts/FreeSans.ttf");
        fontProvider.register( "/Users/user/Downloads/MyFonts/NotoSansCJKsc-Regular.otf");
        fontProvider.register( "/Users/user/Downloads/MyFonts/arialuni.ttf");
        CssAppliers cssAppliers = new CssAppliersImpl(fontProvider);
        // HTML
        HtmlPipelineContext htmlContext = new HtmlPipelineContext(cssAppliers);
        htmlContext.setTagFactory(Tags.getHtmlTagProcessorFactory());
        // Pipelines
        ElementList elements = new ElementList();
        ElementHandlerPipeline pdf = new ElementHandlerPipeline(elements, null);
        HtmlPipeline html = new HtmlPipeline(htmlContext, pdf);
        CssResolverPipeline css = new CssResolverPipeline(cssResolver, html);

        // XML Worker
        XMLWorker worker = new XMLWorker(css, true);
        XMLParser p = new XMLParser(worker);
        p.parse(new ByteArrayInputStream((HTML.toString().getBytes("UTF-8"))), Charset.forName("UTF-8"));

        PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(1);
        PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell();

        for (Element e : elements) {
            System.out.println(e);
            cell.addElement(e);
        }
        table.addCell(cell);
        document.add(table);
        // step 5
        document.close();
    }
}[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

Comment: @Bruno Lowagie : is it wrong way of registering the fonts

Comment: You register different fonts (`FreeSans`, `THSarabunNew`, `NotoSansCJKsc`,...), but you never use them. You only use `font-family:Times New Roman` in your HTML. That can't ever work.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie : It is not working Though I removed style=\"font-size:12.0pt; font-family:Times New Roman\" from body tag

Comment: @BrunoLowagie : Do I need to set each and every font in the Chunk of each element?

Comment: You need to define the appropriate `font-family` for every `<p>` (or every `<div>`, or every `<span>`). People often use `MS Arial Unicode` either in the `FontProvider` (they render everything using `arialuni.ttf` regardless of the font used in the HTML), or in the `font-family`. That's because Arial Unicode supports many languages (but unfortunately not all; it is technically impossible to support every language in a single font).

Comment: @BrunoLowagie : Any alternative for this Problem. Because my html string may contain any language . it can be Chinese or Japanese, Korean,Thai ..etc.

Comment: No, not yet. This may be solved with the pdfCalligraph module in iText 7 (iText 7 automatically detects the language based on the Unicode value of the characters), but XML Worker hasn't been ported to iText 7 yet. Note that iText 5 (or earlier) don't support Hindi. iText 7 is the first iText version that supports Devanagari, Tamil, etc.

Comment: Hi This worked for me . kept style="font-family: Arial Unicode MS, FreeSans;" in body tag. but have these problems  arabic is not displayed correctly and khmer is completely blank

Comment: Arabic requires you to switch to a right-to-left writing system. See [How to convert Arabic HTML to PDF?](http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-convert-arabic-html-pdf) Khmer isn't probably not supported by Arial Unicode MS, nor FreeSans. As for iText, you probably need iText 7 and the iText 7 pdfCalligraph add-on if you need Khmer support. Unfortunately, XML Worker for iText 7 hasn't been released yet.

Comment: For Khmer, check this link related to render to pdf: http://ask.osify.com/qa/613